# Select random rows that match string

Tags: r

I want to randomly select rows from `df2` that matches `Birth_Sex`. The number of rows selected should be equal to the number of rows in `df1` (2 in this example).

df1

```
  Birth_Sex
  1999_1
  1969_1
```

df2

```
 ID          Birth_Sex
 123113      1999_1
 123123      1992_0
 123233      1959_0
 124513      1969_1
 124993      1969_1
 124545      1969_1
```

Example output

```
 ID          Birth_Sex
 124545      1969_1
 123113      1999_1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each entry of `Birth_Sex` in `df1` we first find the row numbers which have that entry in `df2` and select index of any one row to subset `df2`.

```
df2[sapply(df1$Birth_Sex, function(x) {
      inds = which(df2$Birth_Sex %in% x)
     if(length(inds) > 1) sample(inds, 1) else inds
}), ]


#      ID Birth_Sex
#1 123113    1999_1
#4 124513    1969_1
```

Answer (score 3):

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
 df2 %>% 
   inner_join(df1) %>% 
   group_by(Birth_Sex) %>% 
   sample_n(1)
Joining, by = "Birth_Sex"
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   Birth_Sex [2]
      ID Birth_Sex
   <int> <chr>    
1 124993 1969_1   
2 123113 1999_1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the `data.table` solution as well

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)[setDT(df2), nomatch = 0L,on = 'Birth_Sex'][, .SD[sample(.N, 1)], by = Birth_Sex]

#   Birth_Sex     ID
#1:    1969_1 124513
#2:    1999_1 123113
```